# sizeWIthAttributes amazingly slow in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

A little background: I am writing an app that contains a slider to change the font size used throughout the entire app. While a user slides the slider, the user sees the app's font grow bigger and smaller in real time. A lot of my UI relies on `NSString`'s `sizeWithAttributes` to calculate intrinsic content sizes and stuff like that.

I initially started to write this app in Objective-C, and now I am migrating to Swift. After a while I noticed that my font-slider did not perform the way it used to. It used to go smooth, now for every new font size it appears to stutter a lot.

As it turns out, the decrease in performance is caused by `sizeWithAttributes`. Which turns out to be MUCH slower in Swift than it was in Objective C. I performed a simple test (on an iPhone 6) that executes `sizeWithAttributes` 100,000 times in both Swift and in Objective C. The result:

- Objective C (NSString): 0,35 seconds
- Swift (String): 13,6 seconds

So Swift's implementation is almost 40 times slower!! Can somebody advise me what to do here? Can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it is not `sizeWithAttributes` that is slow, it is the way I typed the dictionary!

If I run this code:

```
let size = string.sizeWithAttributes(attributes)
```

and `attributes` is typed as `[String:AnyObject]` it is many times slower than if `attributes` is types as `[NSObject:AnyObject]`!

Problem solved by using `[NSObject:AnyObject]` as the type for attributes from now on!

Edit: if I type the attributes as `Dictionary` it is EVEN faster than `[NSObject:AnyObject]`